# How to send a variable route-to-route in Silex 2?

Tags: php, global, silex

Making my first Silex Application and I need some help, I'm writting a route to show an item and then edit it, so first of all this is my 'get' route which receive the code of the item to show its details.

```
$app->get('/cat/productos_edit/{key}', function($key) use($app){

$app['twig']->addGlobal('itemtoedit', $key); //This is how I'm trying to do it

return $app['twig']->render('catalogo/productos/edit.html',[
    'title' => 'Catálogo - Productos'
  ]);
});
```

So in 'post' route I need to get that variable to edit the item,

```
 $app->post('/cat/productos_edit/', function() use($app){
    echo $app['itemtoedit'];
 })->bind('cat.productos.edit');
```

But then I got this error:

[image: Silex error]

So I think that maybe I'm missing something, Hope that ypu can help me.

Answer (score 3):

PHP / Silex will not keep any context between your get and post so IMHO you should do that :

```
$app->post('/cat/productos_edit/{key}', function($key) use($app){
    // get your item from database with its key
    // update item with your post payload
})->bind('cat.productos.edit');
```

Comment: Definetely, the "trick" is to use the same key in the POSTING url you used for getting the item with posting the new data. Be sure to make your security checks, othwerise anyone could post data to a specific URL and change your items! (this is, among other things, why the CSRF token was created for)

Comment: Thank you, yeah I guess I'll make a hidden input to save that key, sure I already implement CSRF protecction

Comment: Or just link your submit url to 'cat.productos.edit' in your twig template